# Webbrowser inside ListBox WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've got a ListBox and I want each Item of the ListBox items to be displayed in a seperate WebBrowser, I know it sounds like a bad idea but I have to make it this way.
So this is my partial code to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
<ListBox Margin="2,786,-14,-34" ItemsSource="{Binding comments}" DataContext="{Binding BindsDirectlyToSource=True}" Name="commentsListBox" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                            <StackPanel Width="311">
                                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding poster_username}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Width="Auto" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Segoe WP Semibold" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding comment_text}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" MaxHeight="100" />-->
                                <phone:WebBrowser Source="{Binding comment_text}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="23,786,0,0" Name="commentsWebBrowser" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="453" Width="440" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=commentsListBox}" Background="Black" Foreground="{x:Null}"  OpacityMask="Black" Opacity="0" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

How do I bind between the data from the ListBox to the Webbrowser?
I've seen that many people searched for this but I didn't find an answer yet!
Would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a WebBrowser is a bad idea. If you need to show some text with HTML formatting, use HTMLTextBox or HTMLViewer from MSP Toolkit (http://msptoolkit.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I need to mention that using the MSP Toolkit is a bad idea. the HTMLViewer is throwing an exception and I can even know how to fix it.
The property 'Margin' was not found in type 'Paragraph'

Comment: I think it is a problem with your HTML, the HTMLViewer does not support Margin on P. Remove it before displaying.

Comment: I have been looking everywhere for an HTMLTextBox-like control. This is the first question on SO pointing me to it, after lots of googling and searching. Huge thanks!